# Difference between a research paper and technical note

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, paper-submission, online-publication

What is the difference between "Research Article" and "Technical Note"?

What purpose do they serve?

Comment: I don't recall having seen the terminology "technical note" before, and I suspect it may mean different things in different fields or even different journals in the same field. I have seen (and even written) technical reports. These were usually early versions of papers, or parts of papers, or minor pieces of research that would not be publishable on their own.